# What's the relation of different apache2 folders on mac?

Tags: apache, apache2, localhost, virtualhost

There are 2 folders have apache2 stuff in it and some of them are duplicated. I wonder what's the relationship between them and which one does apache server actually use? They are

```
/opt/local/apache2
/private/etc/apache2
```

And I want to see which default index.html is actually used by apache and I modified both

```
/opt/local/apache2/htdocs/index.html
/Library/WebServer/Documents/index.html.en (there is no index.html in this folder)
```

But I still see "It works!" instead of the string I put in.

Comment: i don't know about `/opt/local/apache2`. anyways, kindly check the `apache2` config found in `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` and look for the `DocumentRoot`. By default, this points to `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`. The "It works!" string is displayed on the index page `index.html.en`.

Comment: @rui I did some research and seems like the default behavior is using /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf. Sitll don't know that's /opt/local/apache2/httpd.conf is about. They are mostly the same but with different configurations.